# What are expressions with fractional powers called?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, terminology

What are expressions with fractional powers, e.g. $x^{\frac{3}{4}}$, called in contrast to "monomials" for positive integer powers?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. How are variables with integral exponents called? I don't think there would be a special name, though!

Comment: @Kannappan : It is standard to call variables with *positive* integral exponents monomials, even when several powers of several variables are involved (i.e. $x^2 y^3$ is a monomial).

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva Something seriously wrong with me. I realise that now. It is mentioned even in the question. But, Thank You, Patrick.